# Eclipse bundles not loaded from plugins directory since 4.9

Tags: eclipse-plugin

We are running an OSGI application in a servlet container, using the servletbridge. Since the upgrade to eclipse 4.9, bundles in the /eclipse/plugins directory are not found anymore automatically. If we add them to the config.ini, everything works fine. Before we upgraded to 4.9 the bundles were also found without adding them to config.ini.

Is there a way to get the automatic detection from pre 4.9 back?

Comment: Solution is, no problem on eclipse side. Just missing update configurator plugin :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have the plugin org.eclipse.update.configurator. It may got lost due to the change in a feature.